# Is it possible to fetch data from my website which is live to the simple mysql database in my system?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

Suppose the users of my website uploads a pdf on my website which is live on the internet. Then is there a way that those files after being uploaded gets stored in my mysql database on my system(laptop) directly.

To refine more, would it matter if one uses mySql database on his local system(localhost) or on a live website to store data? , will the database fail to store data if the website is hosted online?

If the question is not clear to anyone in any sort please mention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of nuances to your question, and I'll try to address as many of them as I can.

I would not store files directly in the database. You certainly *can*, but in general you're going to get better performance and other ancillary benefits from storing files as a file in the file system. Store metadata in the database, including at the very least the file name and path on disk (perhaps you want to store more, like the uploader's account information, the size, a long-form text description, and so on, but at least store the path and filename). Then, in your application, fetch the filename from the database and serve the file instead of a database BLOB. One reason is that MySQL performance can really suffer if you don't do this properly.

Let's say you decide to defy my suggestion and store the file as some BLOB data in your database, how can you replicate that to your laptop? Your laptop isn't going to be powered on and connected to the internet all the time, in any case even if you had a server at home running 24 hours a day your hosting provider still should have better uptime than your home does. What should happen to the upload if you were hosting the database on your laptop, but your laptop was off (or rebooting for system updates)? So you should host the database at the hosting provider and somehow sync it to your local machine. MySQL provides several methods of this; replication, export and import of .sql files, or exporting binary logs. These each have tradeoffs that you'll want to consider depending on your needs.

But remember how I said you can get other ancillary benefits from storing the file on the file system directly? One of those is that you can rely on file transfer techniques to get the file to your local machine. SFTP, SCP, SyncThing, WebDAV, and any other way you can imagine transferring files can be used to get the remote file to your local system. You wouldn't automatically get the database metadata, but that didn't seem like much of a requirement from your question, so you'd have easy access to the file as uploaded, as quickly as you want.

So there are plenty of ways to accomplish this, and without more details on your question it's tough to recommend a solution, but you have plenty of options available.